# Finding and removing unknown value from url

Tags: javascript, url

Im writing a bit of js that would do a bit of cleaning of the pathname. So far, I have the following:

```
var corePageUrl = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
if (corePageUrl.indexOf("/account/logon")>=0||corePageUrl.indexOf("/account/summary")>=0)) {
  // do function here    
}
```

Basically, the function needs to do the following: Take the pathname, strip the trailing / from it, and if there is anything beyond those two `.indexOf` statements that qualify the if statement, strip it out. Numerous google searches have lead me nowhere, and as I am starting to get the handle on more complicated javascript issues, this escapes me.

Im not asking anyone to code this for me, moreso help me with the logic that would lead me to a desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want some basic string operations. You mean something like this?

```
var url = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase(),
    i = -1, // var for indexOf
    lookFor = ['/account/logon', '/account/summary'], // what to look for
    j = lookFor.length; // var for loop
// remove query
i = url.indexOf('?');
if (i !== -1) { // has query
    url = url.slice(0, i); // trim
    i = -1; // reset i for later
}
// remove trailing /
while (url.slice(-1) === '/') { // has trailing /
    url = url.slice(0, -1); // trim it
}
// trim url in special cases 
while (i === -1 && j) { // find a match
    i = url.indexOf(lookFor[--j]); // remember to decrease loop counter
}
if (i !== -1) {
    i = i + lookFor[j].length; // position of end of match
    url = url.slice(0, i); // trim after it
}
url; // resulting url
```

---

```
// Alternately,
// remove query
url = url.split('?', 1)[0]; // get the segment before the first ? (all if no ?)
// remove trailing /
url = url.match(/^([\s\S]*?)\/*$/)[1]; // capture group excludes trailing "/"s
// etc
```

---

Examples:

```
http://example.com/some/random///?thing=in_my_url
http://example.com/some/random

http://hilario.us/page/account/summary/place?stuff
http://hilario.us/page/account/summary
```

Comment: Would this also account for slicing out querystring parameters?

Comment: If there is a match with an item in `lookFor`, yes. If you want the `?` any thereafter removed in every case, do it before removing trailing `/`s.

Comment: I'm not saying any of this code is by any means optimised (e.g. the trim could be changed to use `slice` minimal times) but I just realised that removing the query can be done _really quickly_ `url = url.split('?', 1)[0]; // get the segment before the first ? (all if no ?)`

Comment: ..If you're happy with RegExp then you could do the trim trailing `/` via `url = url.match(/^([\s\S]*?)\/*$/)[1];`. Why do I think these things just before I sleep?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the function to do something like:

**Input**: `http://www.example.com/account/logon/foo?bar=baz`.

**Output**: `http://www.example.com/account/logon`

You could easily do this with regular expressions and capture the part of the URL you want to match.

```
var url = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase(),
    match;

if (match = url.match(/.*\/account\/(?:logon|summary)/)) {
    // do function here    
}
```

Where `match` would contain URL including everything up until `/account/logon` or `/account/summary`.